# Accurate sum of a range object in O(1)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently created a function calculating the sum of an arbitrary `range` object in \$O(1)\$:

```
def sum_of_range(range_obj):
    """Calculates the sum of a range object (Python 3) in O(1).

    This function always returns a python integer representing the sum 
    without loss of precision (as would happen if it uses intermediate
    floating point values).
    """
    start, stop, step = range_obj.start, range_obj.stop, range_obj.step
    len_ = len(range_obj)
    if step > 0:
        if start >= stop:
            return 0
        # Find the last "really" included number. Subtract one from stop
        # because the stop is not included in ranges.
        upper = (stop - 1 - start) // step * step + start
    else:
        if stop >= start:
            return 0
        # In case the step is negative we need to add one to the difference
        # instead of subtracting one.
        upper = (stop - start + 1) // step * step + start
    sum_first_and_last = upper + start
    return (sum_first_and_last * len_) // 2
```

I used "random" tests to verify that it works:

```
import random

for i in range(100000):  # make a lot of random tests
    up = random.randint(-10000, 10000)
    lo = random.randint(-10000, 10000)
    step = random.randint(-25, 25)
    if step == 0:  # steps of zero are not possible
        continue
    rg = range(lo, up, step)
    assert sum_of_range(rg) == sum(rg)
```

Is there any room for improvement? Especially (but not only):

- Code readability
- Code performance
- Should I replace the random tests with explicit tests or can I neglect explicit tests? Or should I include both?

Comment: Not clear why you hoisted the `len_` computation. You only use it once, at the end of the routine. So no performance advantage for hoisting. In cases of early exit, actually a deficit. And distance between load into local variable and use raises clarity issues.

Comment: Now that you mention it... no idea why it's hoisted. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's get a closer look at the sum you're trying to calculate:

$$start + (start+step) + (start+2 \times{}step) + \ldots + (start + (len-1)\times{} step)$$

Which can be reordered as:

$$start + \ldots + start + step + 2\times{}step + \ldots + (len-1)\times{}step$$

Which gives you a nice formula regardless of the sign of `start` or `step` or even the value of `stop`:

$$start \times{} len + step \times\frac{len(len-1)}{2}$$

All the complexity being hidden in the `len(range_obj)` call. So you can just write:

```
def sum_of_range(range_obj):
    """Calculates the sum of a range object (Python 3) in O(1).

    This function always returns a python integer representing the sum
    without loss of precision (as would happen if it uses intermediate
    floating point values).
    """

    length = len(range_obj)
    step_counts = length * (length - 1) // 2
    return range_obj.start * length + range_obj.step * step_counts
```

Comment: Ah, that's really clever, it took a moment to realize that one of `len` and `len-1` is even so their product is even as well and one can safely use floor division. Thanks.

Comment: @MSeifert Yes, thats basic sum from 0 to n: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Answer (score -3):

`range_obj` is not a container, and you cannot rely on `len(range_obj)` being \$O(1)\$. A simple experiment

```
$ python -mtimeit "len(range(10))"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.158 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "len(range(10000000))"
10 loops, best of 3: 188 msec per loop
```

shows that it is in fact linear.

The bright side is that you don't need `len` at all. You need a number of elements, and even though it is numerically equal to `len`, it can (and should) be computed as

```
    len_ = (obj.stop - obj.start) // obj.step
```

Comment: At least on my computer it's constant, what python and python version are you using?

Comment: You're probably testing in Python 2, but either way, you can't reasonably pin the linear time on `len` as you're timing the creation of the range object too. Instead use the setup argument to remove this possibility, as then you can time only `len`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839032/python-how-to-calculate-the-length-of-a-range-without-creating-the-range#comment51600368_31839032

Comment: To expand on my last comment, I used: `python -m timeit -s "r=range(10)" "len(r)"`, where I changed; Python versions, the size of the range, and used `xrange` and `range` in Python 2, and found no reasonable (0.1usec) change in time.